# How to fix inconsistent results from a query in Heroku Postgres?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, heroku, flask

I'm developing a blog application using Flask + Heroku Postgres.
I'm trying to get the posts from my database and it kind of worked.
The problem is: when I run the query at my PC, I get a result and when I run the exactly same query at the web application on heroku, I get a completely different result which is also completely different of the results I get for running the same query at PGAdmin / Console.

I guess I have about 8 rows in my posts table.
Running the query at PGAdmin / Console, I get 3 rows (1, 2, 5).
Running at my localhost application, I get 4~5 rows (the same of running at console + another 2 that ramdomly "decides" to show up or not which I don't know the indexes). The same thing happens at the Heroku application but with different posts showing up or not.

PS: The WHERE condition does not affect the results since all the posts have ativo=1.

My query is:

```
SELECT p.id, titulo, TO_CHAR(data, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), imagem,
CONCAT(nome, ' ', sobrenome), texto, ativo FROM posts as p  INNER 
JOIN usuarios as u ON p.autor=u.id WHERE ativo=1 ORDER BY p.id desc;
```

Comment: you sure the data is the same on the local server and remote server?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the same database for all of them.

Comment: i mean the same data (records) not the same database..

Comment: Well, I saw the problem just now after searching for a long time. Actually, it is the same data in the same database. The problem was because I forgot to commit the insert query (shame on me, long code sorry), so I think it was ending up showing some results that wasn't actually in the database. Since  I was not getting any error messages, I thought it was a heroku postgres problem. Sorry and thank you for your time.